# RTX 3060 Blender long loading texture times. Sometimes crashes

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hardware

Whenever i import a texture in material preview view blender becomes unresponsive and i need to wait 20-30 seconds before it unfreezes.

Its even longer if i switch from modelling view without textures to material view. Sometimes it just crashes without any error message.

Cycles render preview works nicely. Its just Eevee material preview that is really laggy

My specs:
Windows 10 20h
Blender 2.91
3060 ti Gigabyte OC pro
I5-10400f
16 gb 2666 cl13 ram
B460 MSI mortar

Comment: Try upgrading or downgrading the drivers for the GPU